# How to get Latitude and Longitude for particular city or street without using google map?

Tags: java, java-me, latitude-longitude, jsr179

How to get Latitude and Longitude for particular city or street or location without using google map?
For example user entered city name is "Chennai" and i need to show only Latitude and Longitude for that city. How to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called Geocoding, and requires matching a place name up to a latitude and longitude.

You can either code a known list of place name/lat-lons into your app, read them in at runtime and search through them when required, or you can use an online Geocoding service such as [this one from Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html), or [this one from Google](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Answer (score 2):

check [Obtaining geographic coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aObtaining_geographic_coordinates) at Wikipedia page

Answer (score 2):

Google provides reverse geocoding - please go through [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) link

also for example below web service gives you the address of lat long provided in the parameter but hte response is in json, see [this](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true) link

if you want to get response in xml then check [here](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.. Finally I fixed it by getting the lat long from the server side.  [**This**](http://javaho.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/server-side-sample-code-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-given-address-using-google-map-api/) link has the sample code for getting lat and long from java.  Hope it helps some one.

```
private static final String GEOCODE_REQUEST_URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&";
    private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager());
    String strLatitude;
    String strLongtitude;
        public void getLongitudeLatitude(String address) {
            try {
                StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(GEOCODE_REQUEST_URL);
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(address)) {
                    urlBuilder.append("&address=").append(URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8"));
                }

                final GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(urlBuilder.toString());
                try {
                    httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream(), getMethod.getResponseCharSet());

                    int data = reader.read();
                    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                    while ((data = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            writer.write(buffer, 0, data);
                    }

                    String result = writer.toString();
                    System.out.println(result.toString());

                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                    InputSource is = new InputSource();
                    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader("<"+writer.toString().trim()));
                    Document doc = db.parse(is);

                    strLatitude = getXpathValue(doc, "//GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat/text()");
                    System.out.println("Latitude:" + strLatitude);

                    strLongtitude = getXpathValue(doc,"//GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng/text()");
                    System.out.println("Longitude:" + strLongtitude);


                } finally {
                    getMethod.releaseConnection();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private String getXpathValue(Document doc, String strXpath) throws XPathExpressionException {
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile(strXpath);
            String resultData = null;
            Object result4 = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result4;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                resultData = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
            }
            return resultData;


    }
```